# XSS Payload That Can Bypass Special Character Check

Tags: xss, audit, .net, sdlc

I developed the following C# algorithm to prevent XSS attacks:

```
private bool Is_There_XSS_Payload(string arg)

{
    
   Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    
   bool result = regex.IsMatch(arg);
    
   return result;
    
 }
```

If the arg parameter contains any non-alphanumeric character, it returns false and does not make progress with the parameter.

Here the question is, can any XSS payload bypass this algorithm? Do I need a data encoding algorithm, or is only this validation enough to prevent XSS attacks?

Comment: Have you consulted : https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html or https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DotNet_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html  or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder?view=netframework-4.7.2 ?  Try not to invent your own protection when there are pre-written libraries to do things for you.